# Form AJAX PHP email sending problems

Tags: php, ajax, email

Thats the code i use:

HTML:

```
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "stackoverflow@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";


    // Send the email.
    mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Using this code I get the success message but I don't recieve email.
email function is supported by the server. If i just add a sample function:

```
mail( "stackoverflow@gmail.com", "dummy", "hi!" );
```

as a first line I do get this email.

Answer (score 1):

Every object you try instantiate incorrectly. Try something like

```
var a = $('#myId'); // a jquery object

// you dont need to pass it again as $(a) this is wrong 

// use below instead of $(a)

// right way to call method in jquery change you every instance

a.submit(function (e) { 
  // your code ....
});
```

Comment: thanx for pointing on this, but it's not the issue. AJAX call is successful and I get the success message from php script, but I don't receive the email.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";

$email_headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
```